# Load more when scrolled to bottom in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my post-card page(only the specific part) where i am displaying data from fetched Api.

```
fetchMoreData(){
    this.setState({
        index: this.state.index + 5 
    })
}
    componentDidMount(){
        window.addEventListener('scroll', this.onScroll);
        this.fetchMoreData();
    }

    onScroll = () => {
        $(window).scroll(function() {   
            if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
                this.fetchMoreData();
            }
         });
       }
```

As My API is a testing API i fetch all the data in my posts page and then pass it  to my post-card page so on change of this.state.index it displays more item.

The issue I am facing is that I get an error that this.fetchMoreData() is not a function. Feel free to point out any mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
onScroll = () => {
    $(window).scroll(() => {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
            this.fetchMoreData();
        }
    });
}
```

If you use `function` it will be called in the context of the `window` object (in your case). You can use closures to save parent context, like this:

```
onScroll = () => {
    const that = this;

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
            that.fetchMoreData();
        }
    });
};
```

But arrow functions bind `this` argument to that of the parent scope, so `this` will link to your component class. And it is much elegant and easier solution than using of `function`, especially you already using arrow functions in your component.

Comment: can you please explain.

Comment: added some explanation

Answer (score 1):

Make `fetchMoreData` an arrow function just like `onScroll`

```
fetchMoreData = () => {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use es6 arrow function because because you need to bind this value from function to our class. so this won't work `$(window).scroll(function() {`. so you can u do like this.

```
$(window).scroll(() => {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
            this.fetchMoreData();
        }
    });
```